# r blogdown -- serve_site hangs in Windows

Tags: r, blogdown

Please, I'd love some troubleshooting suggestions/tips...

After editing a .md file in the content/post directory, I then `blogdown:::serve_site()`.  At that point the **site will build once**, and the web server will serve the site.  However, at the same time, **RStudio hangs** and requires a "Session/Terminate R..." (cannot edit in the edit tab, cannot file browsing in the Files tab, etc.)  `servr::demon_stop(<pid>)` does not stop the server.

The content I am editing is in the content directory of this repo:  https://github.com/data-and-visualization/blogdown2-rfun

Maybe noteworthy:  When I invoke "Session > Terminate R" I get the following Window OS Dialogue box message:

> File Listing Error
>
> Error navigating to ~:
>
> unable to establish connection with R session

---

```
session_info("blogdown")

Session info ----------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (1.1.453)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2018-08-14                  

Packages --------------------------------------------------
 package   * version  date       source        
 backports   1.1.2    2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 base64enc   0.1-3    2015-07-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 BH          1.66.0-1 2018-02-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 blogdown    0.8      2018-07-15 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 bookdown    0.7      2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 digest      0.6.15   2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 evaluate    0.11     2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 glue        1.3.0    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 graphics  * 3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 grDevices * 3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 highr       0.7      2018-06-09 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 htmltools   0.3.6    2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 httpuv      1.4.5    2018-07-19 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 jsonlite    1.5      2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 knitr       1.20     2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 later       0.7.3    2018-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 magrittr    1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 markdown    0.8      2017-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 methods   * 3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 mime        0.5      2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 promises    1.0.1    2018-04-13 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 R6          2.2.2    2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 Rcpp        0.12.18  2018-07-23 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rlang       0.2.1    2018-05-30 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rmarkdown   1.10     2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 rprojroot   1.3-2    2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 servr       0.10     2018-05-30 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 stats     * 3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 stringi     1.1.7    2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
 stringr     1.3.1    2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tinytex     0.6      2018-07-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 tools       3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 utils     * 3.5.1    2018-07-02 local         
 xfun        0.3      2018-07-06 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
 yaml        2.2.0    2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it in `R`? Or reinitiate `RStudio`?

Comment: Great questions.  Thanks for the thoughts.  I had not tried running it in R or reinstalling RStudio.  I've just done both and it's still not working properly.  In the process I was reminded that I have a problem with stringi.  I cannot seem to install the latest source (v 1.2.4?), so I'm able to install the binary 1.1.7.  (I'm not sure that stringi is the problem but it does suggest some [other] problem).

Comment: Which Hugo theme are you using in your `blowdown` site?

Comment: Future Imperfect -- https://themes.gohugo.io/future-imperfect/

Comment: I had no problem in either with `blogdown:serve_site()` and visualize it in a browser. Can't manage to add a post though... I tried to create a post with different extension (`.md`, `.Rmd`) and nothing happens... Maybe this theme is not supported by `blogdown`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!  I have the same problem with a different project using the hugo academic theme.  Interestingly, It all of my blogdown projects build at the netlify.com host.  My problem seems to be the local serve_site() will hanging on my windows workstations.  Hmmmm.  I'm stumped.  I appreciate your helping me think this through.  Thanks.

Comment: Any updates on the solution to this issue?

Comment: @VilmantasGegzna  -->  No.  There is no solution to this.  I have the problem on two workstations with more than one hugo theme.  The sites build fine at Netlify.  I have no real problems with my r/RStudio installations on my workstations.

Comment: Upon further investigation the solution is to rebuild the site starting from scratch.  I was hoping to find some troubleshooting solutions to my existing site.  In any case, if I create a new blogdown and then migrate my existing rmarkdown I can get the site working again.  In some cases I have to edit the YAML file to take into account changes in the themes requirements.

Comment: @JohnLittle This solved it for me! I deleted `public` and `resources` folders. Then I did `blogdown::build_site()` followed by `blogdown::serve_site()`. Perfect!

Comment: This seems deeply problematic: it can cause weird issues and difficult-to-trace changes if you're using git for version control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Following advice from comments by @John Little and @Mel I deleted the `public` folder (@Mel suggests also removing the `resources` folder, but I don't have such a folder) and rebuilt the site. This worked somewhat, but the problems kept returning. After that I followed https://www.oipapio.com/question-677654 and ran `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` and the problems disappeared.